# Multiple instances of jQuery hide/show doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a simple bit of code that uses a dropdown to change the display property of some divs but I'd like to be able to have separate instances of it on the same page.
It doesn't work right now because it uses class names to define the content to show and hide.

```
<div>
<select id="selectMe">
<option value="option1">option1</option>
<option value="option2">option2</option>
<option value="option3">option3</option>
<option value="option4">option4</option>
</select>
<div class="group option1">asdf</div>
<div class="group option2">kljh</div>
<div class="group option3">zxcv</div>
<div class="group option4">qwerty</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('.option1').show();
    $('#selectMe').change(function () {
        $('.group').hide();
        $('.'+$(this).val()).show();
    })
});
</script>
```

Is there a different way of targeting the .group divs so that I can repeat the whole block of HTML on the page and have it still work?

Hope you can help!

Comment: You could just target you elements by [index](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have created a wrapper anyways so make use of it. When you target use the parent/container as the context so that you can have it repeated anywhere else on the page. You can use [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to reach to the parent div and select the `.group` or `.option` within the parent of the dropdown.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('.option1').show();

    $('#selectMe').change(function () {
       var container = $(this).closest('.container');
        $('.group', container ).hide(); //Select only the group under its parent
        $('.' + this.value, container).show(); //Select only the target div under its parent
    })
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gSZnv/)

Comment: Just a quick followup, do you know what might cause this to return a "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: ." error? I copied the code exactly into my site and am using jQuery 1.9.1.

Comment: I just converted into plain text before trying again and it works now. Something odd with jsFiddle perhaps.